# Préparatif et préparation, quelle est la différence?

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire

Je n'arrive pas à discerner le sens profond de chacun de ces deux mots. Et par conséquent à les utiliser correctement. Par exemple:

- j'étais presque absent durant les préparatifs pour le mariage.
- j'étais presque absent durant les préparations pour le mariage.

Comment: Attention que selon moi on devrait utiliser "préparation" au singulier ici. Au pluriel je l'entend plutôt comme des préparations culinaires.

Comment: @LaurentS. Hahah, moi ça connote des produits pharmaceutiques ou au contenu étrange !

Answer (score 5):

Les deux mots sont souvent interchangeables, mais il existe une nuance dans leur sens.
Les "préparatifs" sont en fait les petites actions qui mènent à l'évènement qu'on prépare. On l'utilise généralement au pluriel.
La "préparation" désigne plutôt l'ensemble de ces préparatifs, l'action de se préparer dans son ensemble. On l'utilise généralement au singulier.

Par exemple, on peut utiliser les deux mots pour parler du mariage, mais pas pour les mêmes raisons.
Si l'on veut décrire l'organisation du mariage, on pourrait dire :

> Tout le monde était affairé aux préparatifs, à cuisiner, à amener les tables, etc.

Par contre, dans ton exemple, je parlerais de "préparation", puisque ton objectif n'est pas de décrire les étapes, mais d'informer de ton absence durant le processus.

> J'étais presque absent durant la préparation du mariage.

La même question : [Forum WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pr%C3%A9paratif-pr%C3%A9paration.2189915/?hl=fr)

Comment: Aussi, `préparation` peut avoir une connotation temporelle. La `préparation` est la phase durant laquelle on réalise les `préparatifs`.

Answer (score 3):

A première vue, ces deux mots sont très proches. Mais *préparatifs* signifierait plutôt: les activités de préparation, alors que *préparation* désignerait le processus de préparation dans sa totalité. Donc la *préparation* serait l'ensemble des *préparatifs*.

Dans votre cas, j'utiliserais plutôt *préparatifs*:

> j'étais presque absent durant les préparatifs du/(pour le) mariage.

Sinon:

> j'étais presque absent durant la préparation du mariage.

Answer (score 1):

A propos de préparatifs et préparation d'un mariage:

> Lorsque tous les préparatifs d'un mariage s'achèvent les uns après les autres, alors la préparation du mariage se déroule parfaitement bien.

Comment: J'upvote, je ne vois pas pourquoi cette réponse de sapienz devrait être marquée d'un -1.

Comment: @Frank > On a tout juste la base d'une réponse, l'auteur pourrait élaborer sur la chronologie par exemple, plutôt que laisser le lecteur comprendre ce qui peut sembler logique à ceux qui ont bien saisi la nuance entre les 2 mots, ce qui n'est pas le cas de l'OP justement...